# Accessing data from code behind in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am using devexpress JS Charts which they accept data in a format of:

```
[{ category: 'Oceania', value: 35 },{ category: 'Europe', value: 728 }]
```

I am able to get the exact same format in my back end code by converting a DataTable to a Json. (I am getting the datatable after i run a couple of queries based of the user's selection)

Everything was working fine untill i decided to use an UpdatePanel to avoid the postbacks in the page every time the user was selecting an option (Please note that i am not experienced in something like this). Now ,though, i realized that i can't call a non static method with javascript in order to get the data.
What i thought i could do is every time i have an ajax postback, i would run a method and insert into a hidden field the data and then grab it with javascript and populate my charts. When i am doing that it's not working as the data is stored as string... I tried a couple of things around it but i simple can't make this work...

I was grabbing the data before (with post back)

```
var data= <%=GetData()%>
```

The GetData() is a C# method that returns a string

```
private string GetJsonFormat(DataTable table)
```

In order to populate the charts i must use

```
$("#divID").dxPieChart({dataSource: data});
```

If i input the data into an input field and grab it like this

```
var data= $('#inputID').val();
```

It doesn't work because of the string quotes... I even tried to remove the quotes like this

```
data.substring(1,data.length()-1)
```

but didn't work either...

Can someone see an alternative way around this or a fix for this?

Comment: If the data is safe, have you tried using `eval()`?

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach would be to use AJAX. For example, jQuery has built-in functions for getting JSON content from the server.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

It's extremely simple. The easiest approach is to get your button (or whatever triggers the event) to simply call:

```
$.getJSON('url/to/json/content', function(data) {
    // data is the returned JSON object so use it as you like
});
```